# I am trying to write an expression where it would give the below output in Abinitio GDE

Tags: expression, dml, ab-initio

input in zero byte file made in unix:

2000560|Bibek|28

3490679|kjdsk|56

1775679|Samrat|45

my output needed is

Bi

kj

Sa

Answer (score 0):

record
string("|") col1;
string("|") col2
string("\n") col3;
end;

out::transform(in) = begin
out.value::string_substring(in.col2, 1,2);
end;

Answer (score 0):

read file then use reformat. Below is the transformation
out::reformat(in)=
begin
out.out_field:: string_substring(in.field2,0,2);
end;

index starts from 0

Comment: Not readble answer